# "Fressen" oder "essen" menschenähnliche Wesen?

Tags: word-choice

Wäre es richtiger zu sagen

> Androiden (Roboter) fressen nicht.

oder

> Androiden essen nicht.

Welches Wort würde man für prähistorische Vorfahren der Menschheit wählen wie etwa die Neandertaler, Australopithecus oder sogar für "Lucy"?

Und was tun die Klingonen in Star Trek?

Alle sind mehr oder weniger menschenähnliche Humanoiden, und ich als Nichtmuttersprachler würde "essen" verwenden, oder ist das Wort nur und ausschließlich für Menschen geeignet?

Comment: Ich würde für alle menschenähnlichen Lebewesen zunächst einmal das Wort "essen" verwenden. Da Androide ja schon vom Terminus her menschenähnlich sein sollen, würde ich also (ebenso wie für die Klingonen) auch hier "essen" verwenden - außer die Art und Weise legt (wie beim Menschen) die Verwendung von "fressen" nahe, z.B. "Als es Blutpastete gab, haben die Klingonen gefressen wie die Schweine".

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar Ist auch die Lucy genug menschenähnlich um zu "essen"?

Comment: Da geht's dann los mit den Problemen :-) Bei Lucy würde ich sagen, nein, denn Lucy ist ja gerade an der Schwelle vom Affen zum Menschen insofern, als sie zwar aufrecht gehen konnte, aber Kopf und Gehirn eher noch dem von Affen glich. Trotz aufrechten Gangs war sie wohl eher "tierisch".

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar Die Wortwahl hat also vielleicht mehr mit dem Intellekt zu tun? Aber ein Idiot "ißt" wohl auch?

Comment: Das meinte ich nicht. Ich meinte, dass ich Zweifel habe, ob Lucy trotz der Tatsache, dass sie auch zwei Beinen lief, "menschenähnlich" genug ist. Manche Echsenarten können auch längere Strecken auf zwei Beinen laufen - deswegen sind sie aber noch lange nicht menschenähnlich.

Comment: Humanoid bedeutet menschenähnlich. Was ist dann ein menschenähnlicher Humanoid? Ein Pleonasmus.

Comment: @Em1 "Mehr oder weniger" habe ich geschrieben, das ist der Kernpunkt meiner Frage, in welchem Grad das Wesen menschenähnlich sein muß. "Mehr oder weniger" ginge nicht ohne das Adjektiv, oder? Komparieren: "humanoid-humanoider- am humanoidest" wäre für mich unmöglich

Comment: @Beta: Alle sind mehr oder weniger menschenähnlich, alle sind mehr oder weniger humanoid, alle kann man mehr oder weniger als Humanoid bezeichnen. — Es gibt Möglichkeiten, wie du siehst. Es war aber auch kein Kritikpunkt. Ist mir nur aufgefallen und ich fand es klang lustig (im positiven Sinne lustig). Und ich habe es aber auch nicht editiert und so stehen lassen. Ist schon in Ordnung, wollte nur darauf hinweisen, dass beides eigentlich das gleiche bezeichnet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*fressen* kann als "unschön/unsittlich Nahrung zu sich nehmen" verstanden werden und ist im Bezug auf alles, zu dem wir ein wenig Zugneigung/Empathie empfinden, abschätzig.

Da die meisten Anroiden in der Science-Fiction dem Menschen, sogar dem idealen Menschen, nachempfunden sind, werden diese wohl auch die Tischsitten achten und das Wort „fressen“ ist also unangebracht. Außerdem wird Androiden oft Empathie entgegengebracht.

Bei Klingonen ist das jetzt schon eine schwierigere Frage. Hier wäre „fressen“ nicht unangebracht [zumindest ab TNG], allerdings nehmen sie die Nahrung ja auch nur so zu sich, wie es bei ihnen Sitte ist. „Fressen“ würde hier deutlich die nach Menschlichen Maßstäben rüde Art betonen.

Bei Lucy wäre „fressen“ einerseits nicht unangebracht, andererseits würde es vermutlich als abschätzig verstanden, bringen viele Menschen Lucy doch ein wenig Empathie entgegen.

Es ist auch nicht selten, dass man von essenden Haustieren spricht, da diesen oft sehr viel Zuneigung zukommt.

Wenn man zu jemandem sagt „Friss nicht so [in dich rein]!“, dann meine ich das z.B. deutlich abschätzig, um ihn auf seine mangelnden Tischsitten aufmerksam zu machen.

Comment: Danke, und was würdest Du über das Monstrum von Frankenstein sagen? ;)

Comment: @Beta Wenn ich an einem Buch oder Film arbeiten würde, dann würde die Protagonisten wohl "Es frisst gerade!" rufen. Wenn ich allerdings so davon sprechen würde, würde meine Wahl wohl zuerst auf "essen" fallen.

Answer (score 3):

Wer Englisch spricht, kann sich mit folgender Regel behelfen:

Wenn man im Englischen »he« oder »she« (also nicht »it«) sagen würde, dann sagt man im Deutschen »essen«, sonst »fressen«.

Es geht hier in beiden Sprachen um die Abgrenzung zwischen menschlichen und nichtmenschlichen Lebewesen, wobei man hier, in Hinblick auf androide Roboter, auch den Begriff »Lebewesen« etwas ausdehnen muss.

Es gibt weder in Richtung der Maschinen noch in Richtung der Tiere scharfe Grenzen zwischen menschlich und nichtmenschlich, daher kann diese Frage nicht exakt beantwortet werden.

Bei den Maschinen (androide Roboter) halte ich den Ausdruck »fressen« für gänzlich ungeeignet. Da würde ich bei besonders menschenähnlichen Robotern (etwa beim 200-Jahre Mann, dem Jungen aus A.I. oder auch bei C-3PO) von »essen« sprechen. Bei weniger menschenähnlichen (WALL·E, R2-D2) würde ich, vorausgesetzt, sie machen so etwas überhaupt, dann eher von »Nahrung aufnehmen« sprechen. Wobei in diesen Fällen auch unklar ist, ob diese Geräte überhaupt noch als Androide durchgehen, aber das ist dann ohnehin eine andere Frage.

Bei der Abgrenzung zu den Tieren hin würde ich persönlich auf jeden Fall von »essen« sprechen, wenn dabei zumindest gelegentlich Werkzeuge benutzt werden (Stäbchen, Löffel, ...). Auch wenn die Nahrung mit den Händen zum Mund geführt wird, halte ich »essen« für angebracht. Dagegen spricht, dass viele Affen auch ihre Hände bei der Nahrungsaufnahme benutzen. Bei einem Schimpansen, der mit seinen Händen Früchte von einem Baum erntet und sie dann in seinen Mund schiebt, würde ich trotzdem nicht von »essen« sondern von »fressen« sprechen. Wie gesagt: Schwammige Grenze.

Comment: Danke, eine Frage noch: Die Lucy hat ja einen Namen, daher sagen wir wohl in english "she" wenn wir über sie reden? Über haustiere sagen Leute wohl "he" und "she"?